# XSLT 1.0: XML to XML conversion - how to transform Unicode to HTML entity?

Tags: xslt, unicode

I have an input XML that comes from a Unicode system. I have names for products
that look like this:

`<MAKTX>Bear &#38; Friends</MAKTX>`

My XSLT transforms XML to XML. In my output the above line looks like this:
`<MAKTX>Bear&lt;(&gt;&amp;&lt;)&gt;Friends</MAKTX>`

But I expect
`<MAKTX>Bear&amp;Friends</MAKTX>`

I can't change the input XML from my source system.
How do I transform the Unicode `&#38;` to the HTML entity `&amp;`?

Comment: Whatever you did to create that output, it was pretty weird. Please show us.

Comment: Hello Michael, my question set up is wrong. I was mapping the wrong `MAKTX` element which contained more than `&#38;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly there is no need to change anything `&amp;` and `&#38;` are equivalent markup for a `&` in both XML and HTML.

If you use

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

Then some processors are more likely to use the named form but it is not under your direct control from XSLT just as you can not directly control whether `"` or `'` is used around attribute values, it is just a syntactic variation that no HTML system should care about.

Comment: Hello David, thank you but that does not work. I have to transform XML to XML and I am using `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>`. Is there any other way?

Comment: Tell us what you are doing, and we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @Peter No XML or HTML system will distinguish `&amp` from `&#38;` so there is no problem to solve.

Comment: @David, you are right. I mapped the wrong `<MAKTX>`. The one I need contains `Bear&#60;(&#62;&#38;&#60;)&#62;Friends50g`which is exactly the output I received. I should have stuck to the procedure of providing source and expected output XML and I would have seen my own error. Feel free to downvote my question or can I delete it? Best regards, Peter